# when using spark as just etl process, what is faster between rdd and dataset in Spark2.1?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, dataset, rdd

Hi I'm using spark for etl.

I am just loading json string as rdd from hdfs, parsing them as json, manipulating each json (without aggregation or shuffle) and then save them as json sting to hdfs.

I don't need any query-like actions so don't need columnar data.

But, many reports say that in Spark 2.1, dataset api is faster than rdd.

I'm confusing that what is more suitable for my situation.

Anyone can tell me whatever about this?

Answer (score 0):

In your case Dataframe is the better option, because it is more straight forward.

From your comment, what you want to do can be simply expressed as

spark.read.json("some json file").select("some json fields").write.json("outputpath")

which is all done via dataframe (your json data is read as a dataframe)

Comment: I have to extract inner json object or json array and merge with outer and then renaming columns and converting type are also needed. Is dataframe faster? Programming Intuitiveness is not important for me.

Comment: Dataframe is faster than rdd in mainly 2 ways

1. When you run a query in dataframe, query pass is optimised by a framework.
2. Internal representation of data is more memory efficient.

Neither of the 2 applies to your situation.

Comment: my data is very dirty. so all rows in one file have very different keys -> cause too many columns if integrated. making dataframe overhead is not significant?

Comment: No you dont. The task you described is a simple mapping task of which data representation in memory hardly matters, because you should never fill your executors with that much data. Representation of data start mattering when you need to move data around your nodes. RDD and dataframe does not matter in your use case. I like how you are asking for help here while implying every step along that way that the guy trying to help you is stupid. rofl

Comment: It is said that rdd is faster in spark 1.6 (https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/42027/rdd-vs-dataframe-vs-sparksql.html). do you think it's different from spark 2.1.1 ? I'm just curious about your knowledge and opinion (not intend to arguing with you. sorry if you feel bad ^^;;)